# Is it valid to run a ordered logistic regression with a two-level categorical dependent variable?

Tags: logistic, survey

After much labor, I've yet to come up with the answer to:

Is it valid to run a ordered logistic regression with a two-level categorical dependent variable?

I'm running a logistic regression on a categorical dependent survey response variable ("Most People Can Be Trusted," vs. "You Cannot Trust Most People), against a variety of categorical predictors (age with decile factor levels, household income strata, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

That is a very common usage of logistic regression. Assign one alternative to `0` the other to `1` and compute a logistic regression (the simple two-case, not the complicated "ordered" for more then two alternatives). Usually this is interpreted as modelling the chance of one or the other alternative.

Every two-alternative categorial variable can be viewed as ordered. For example you could consider the two states man and women as being ordered by being increasingly feminine or decreasing male-ish. Things only become difficult if there are more than two alternatives.

Comment: Would the end result of doing a OLR AND a LR with the standard generalized linear model be fairly similar, then?

Comment: To my undestanding, LR and OLP with just two levels are the same. I don't know, whether the implementation in whatever software you use is the same. The more important step towards answering your question is, that every two-alternative categorial can be treated like ordinal.